# Load more and filter (not necessarily in this order)

Tags: filter, pagination, loading

The problem exposing might seems trivial to you. It still isn't clear for me which solution to choose.

Saying that you have a input text where you can type anything. Beneath it a list of ten element and a load more button. Once the user clicks on "load more", ten more elements are added to the list.

My question is, when typing a text to filter, if there is 100 potentials results in the database, should we show the 10 first and a load more button or 20 ? since the user already clicked once on load more, we could expect him to want it to stay as is.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'd stay with the 10 results + load more in the name of consistency and re-using the pattern users are already familiar with